# Автоматически тестирующая система и защита

Tags: java, c++, тестирование, защита

В общем пишу я автоматическую тестирующую систему для олимпиадных (и не очень) задач по информатике, а точнее по программированию. В чем заключается суть? Вот в чем:

1. студент/ученик читает условие задачи
2. студент/ученик решает задачу, пишет код на доступном языке
3. потом отправляет решение на сервер, через веб интерфейс
4. сервер прогоняет прогу по тестам и отправляем результат студенту

(все входные данные считываются из файла input.txt, а выводятся в output.txt). Так вот проблема в 4 пункте, а точнее в защите, необходимо ЗАПРЕТИТЬ доступ скомпилированному приложению (студент отправляет код, сервер его компилит) ко всем файлам, кроме input.txt и output.txt, а также запретить юзать WinApi, сокеты и т.д.

Предположительно надо все это сделать на java, в крайнем случае c++. Идей нет, что можете посоветовать? Ос windows, но если возможно лучше кросс платформенное решение.

p.s. Готовые системы типа ejudge не предлагать.

Comment: я думаю вместо того чтоб все ограничения делать для работающего приложеиня можно распарсить его код и проверить на использование недопустимых библиотек

если под *nix системами гараздо проще ограничить програму, - заменять все переменные среды. изменить права плиложения, - ограничить доступ ко всему кроме содержимого текущей папки

Answer (score 2):

Если вопрос в первую очередь о безопасности, можно все это запускать в виртуальной машине без доступа к файловой системе хоста.

Ограничения в доступе к директориям вне той, где лежит сама программа, в никсах решается очень просто с помощью chroot. Опять в никсах можно реализовать систему строго разграничения прав пользователей.

С API (или системными функциями) посложнее. Для С/С++ можно реализовать собственную версию, очень короткую, libc, в которой будут только функции для записи и чтения файлов, причем они могут проверять имена файлов и ограничить их только заданными (input.txt  и т.д.). Естественно, не будет доступа к сокетам и пр.

Для других языков можно в виртуальной машине удалить нежелательные модули, оставив только нужные. Например, для Java как-то запретить доступ к java.net.*; можно их просто удалить.

Answer (score 0):

> также запретить юзать WinApi, сокеты

просто не линковать с соответствующими библиотеками

А вот доступ к файлам запретить сложнее, наверное. Можно попробовать написать свой вариант iostream.h: сначала проверять имя файла, потом вызывать стандартный метод

Comment: дело в том, что решения задач будут не только на c++, но и на pascal, delphi, возможно java и python ...

Answer (score 0):

В остальных языках также можно ограничивать исполняемый файл набором доступных ему библиотек.
Как вариант, можно парсить подключаемые в коде библиотеки, а в условии указывать какие из библиотек нужно использовать.
А работу с файловой системой можно ограничить сторонними утилитами, их масса. Другое дело что нужно будет указать приложения которые ограничены в доступе, для java например ограничить java.exe который будет исполнять .class файл.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеки, с помощью которых можно ограничить работу файловой системы?

Comment: http://forum.oszone.net/thread-62705.html